# VM RVIZ inits but crashes shortly after start

Tags: ros, rviz, beginner-tutorials, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Notes**

- ROS Indigo / Ubuntu 14.04.5 via VirtualBox 5.0.14 / mbp OS X 10.11.3
- RVIZ runs rgbdslam with no problems `rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam`

**Initial Steps**

- `$ roscore &`
- `$ rosrun using_markers basic_shapes`

**Error**

```
 $ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1457714879.772654975]: rviz version 1.11.10
[ INFO] [1457714879.772826513]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
libGL error: pci id for fd 23: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
[ INFO] [1457714880.177673412]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1457714880.178609213]: OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2).
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Since RVIZ works on it's own, why am I getting issues with RVIZ running with *using_markers* ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228823/vm-rviz-inits-but-crashes-shortly-after-start/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2016-03-25**:
Same problem as well. Ubuntu host with nvidia drivers. Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit guest on Virtual box 5.0.16 and guest additions 5.0.17. How long is VBox going to be blamed for this? We're going on 6 years.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2017-05-23**:
@Constantin S VirtualBox 5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2) May 2017 still crashing with 3D acceleration enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the `VirtualBox 3D acceleration for Ubuntu` problem. If you turn off the `VirtualBox 3D acceleration`, the RViz will work fine, but your CPU will be overused, the `compiz` will take about 70% of your CPU.

I install dual OS in my laptop, then the libGL error is gone. So you may try this.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-08-19**:
I've found that if you users "spheres" in your point clouds that reduces the performance cost by a lot which makes cpu rviz usable for what I'm doing.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-22**:
Epic this worked for me